# How to handle nested structures with ng-repeat using HTML tables in Angular 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let us assume we have following data structure:

```
var data = [
   {
      name: "item name",
      nestedData: [{
         name: "nested name",
         quantity: 1
      },
      {
         name: "nested name 2",
         quantity: 2
      }
      ]
   },
   {
      name: "item name 2",
      nestedData: [{
         name: "nested name 3",
         quantity: 3
      }
      ]
   }
];
```

Standard behavior of `ng-repeat` directive will iterate over high level elements. If we run `ng-repeat="item in data"` it will produce two items.

Is it possible - without using custom directive - to iterate over first item ("item name") twice (multiply it by a length of nestedData array)?

The output I'd like to achieve is:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Nested name</th>
      <th>Nested quantity</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td rowspan="2">item name</td>
         <td>nested name</td>
         <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td ng-hide="true">item name</td>
        <td>nested name 2</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>item name 2</td>
        <td>nested name 3</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Nested `ng-repeat` is not suitable in this situation because there's a need to iterate over `<tr>`'s.

Comment: first you mas aplain your array, in one level use map, with recursive method to access at lower

Comment: Can you tell us how your result looks like

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón Could you explain it in more details? It sounds interesting, but I don't get it.

Comment: Yes, just put `ng-repeat="nestedItem in item.nestedData"` inside the first `ng-repeat`

Comment: @George this not solved if is was inside third level

Comment: @George That's not the case. It's obvious solution, but I need to have top level iterations not nested loop.

Comment: @Landeeyo  You can still access the top level, [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zyp9kqqL/)

Comment: limit with `ng-repeat="item in data|limitTo:1"`

Comment: @George Yes, but I need to have strictly following iterations in the presented data: 1st iteration: { "item name", { "nested name" } }; 2nd { "item name", { "nested name 2" } }; 3rd { "item name 2",  { "nested name 3" } }

Comment: @Landeeyo what is the expected output would look like, just add it to your question

Comment: @nivas More or less like I've written in previous comment (of course it's a bit simplified format).

Comment: @Landeeyo that's what is being output. http://jsfiddle.net/zyp9kqqL/1/ to make sure it's being done like that you can add an [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) to the ng-repeat

Comment: So you want to nest `ngRepeat`. What's the problem?

Comment: Your expected output has a syntax error, you're not giving the nested object a property name.

Comment: Okay, I added some description why I can't use nested `ngRepeat`. I apologize, I should do this from the beginning.

Comment: You can still do this with nested ng-repeat, it's valid HTML to have one table with multiple tbodys, [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zyp9kqqL/4/), this is with the working rowspan

Comment: @Landeeyo would you mind to play with your 'var data' array in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a nested ng-repeat to get your desired result as it's valid HTML to have multiple tbody elements.

Here is a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zyp9kqqL/4/) for a working example

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Nested name</th>
      <th>Nested quantity</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="item in data">
          <tr ng-repeat="nestedItem in item.nestedData">
            <td rowspan="{{item.nestedData.length}}" ng-hide="$index == 1">{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{nestedItem.name}}</td>
            <td>{{nestedItem.quantity}}</td>
          </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Many thanks George :). I didn't know it's possible to set ng-repeat on tbody. Great solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's a different approach to achieve expected output.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    var data = [
         {
            name: "item name",
              nestedData: [
              {
                 name: "nested name",
                 quantity: 1
              },
              {
                 name: "nested name 2",
                 quantity: 2
              },
              {
                 name: "nested name 3",
                 quantity: 3
              }
            ]
         },
         {
            name: "item name 2",
              nestedData: [{
                 name: "nested name 3",
                 quantity: 3
              }
            ]
         }
      ];
 
  var nestedData = [];
  angular.forEach(data, function(item){
    if(item.nestedData.length > 1){
      angular.forEach(item.nestedData, function(nestedItem){
        nestedData.push({
          name : item.name,
          nestedName: nestedItem.name,
          nestedQty: nestedItem.quantity,
          colspan: item.nestedData.length
        });
      });
    } else {
      nestedData.push({
        name : item.name,
        nestedName: item.nestedData[0].name,
        nestedQty: item.nestedData[0].quantity
      });
    }
  });
  
  $scope.data = nestedData;
});
```

```css
tr.multiple > td:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  
<table class="table table-stripped">
   <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Nested name</th>
      <th>Nested quantity</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in data" ng-class="{'multiple': item.colspan > '1' && !$first}">
         <td rowspan="{{item.colspan ? item.colspan : '1'}}">{{item.name}}</td>
         <td>{{item.nestedName}}</td>
         <td>{{item.nestedQty}}</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Vilas. I decided to mark George's answer as correct because it's simpler in given example, but I find your solution also very informative, it can be helpful especially in more complex cases. Thank you very much.